# Ruby Hash statement working in irb and giving error in terminal

Tags: hash, syntax-error, irb, ruby-1.9.2

My hash statement is working fine in try ruby.org where as its giving error in my terminal. Why so?

Here is the error: http://f.cl.ly/items/25330q3X33112u1v370P/err.tiff

Thanks!

Comment: Works for me. Have you tried to actually enter the command in your terminal and not just copy&paste it into your irb session?

Comment: Oops that was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Works for me. Have you tried to actually enter the command in your terminal and not just copy&paste it into your irb session?

[for claiming the answer] :)